# Can Boost assert that a method call instantiation would not compile?

Tags: c++11, boost, instantiation, assert, template-meta-programming

The following code works fine, I am happy with my robust class.

However, asserting that certain method call instantiations do not compile by manually commenting in and out when compiling, is, the least, very tedious. I understand that foreseeing that the compilation will break can only be achieved by actually compiling. This is a catch22 situation. But is there some beautiful way of getting around it without too much code obfuscation?

Does Boost have something to offer?

```
#include <tchar.h>
#include <type_traits>

template<int SOMEMEANINGFULNUMBER>
class RobustClass {

private:
    RobustClass() {}

public:
    static RobustClass<SOMEMEANINGFULNUMBER> instance;

    template <int I = SOMEMEANINGFULNUMBER>
    typename std::enable_if<(I != 2) && (I == SOMEMEANINGFULNUMBER)>::type
    doSomething() {
        // Do something smart and useful!
    }
};

template<int SOMEMEANINGFULNUMBER>
RobustClass<SOMEMEANINGFULNUMBER> RobustClass<SOMEMEANINGFULNUMBER>::instance;

typedef RobustClass<0> RobustClass0;
typedef RobustClass<2> RobustClass2;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    RobustClass<0> robustClass0 = RobustClass0::instance;
    RobustClass<2> robustClass2 = RobustClass2::instance;

    robustClass0.doSomething(); // Compiles and runs fine

    // robustClass2.doSomething(); // Beautifully breaks compilation.
                                   // But I want to wrap this call so 
                                   // that it does NOT break the compilation.
                                   // May be a catch22 wish, however.

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `I != 2` means that `RobustClass<2>` has no `doSomething()`. So as per SFINAE `robustClass2` can be created and it is just that `doSomething()` is not declared. As you mention; all working as intended. Why do you want the option to still leave `robustClass2.doSomething();` in your code if you cannot call it? What additional benefit or value do you have in mind?

Comment: @Yakk Why is the program ill formed?

Comment: @Mus campester robustClass2.doSomething(); should not be in any out and running installations of the compiled code, that is the actual point. But I need to test that it would be impossible to compile the code with such a bad construct in it. The RobustClass could be instantiated with 100ds of values, but doSomething should only be called from an instantiation with SOMEMEANINGFULNUMBER different from 2.

Comment: I understood that the question is asking how you could wrap `robustClass2.doSomething()` so that it doesn't break the compilation. Were you hoping for just a warning perhaps? But now from the comment I'm more confused. It seems that the real question is; will this work to weed out any occurrences of `robustClass2.doSomething();`?

Comment: @Muscampester Ah, I misread part of the technique.  I think the OP did it legal.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you want to be able to check that `RobustClass<2>::doSomething()` cannot be invoked from an instance of type `RobustClass<2>`.

Currently you check for this by forcing a build break, then commenting it out.  This is annoying, because each check requires manually editing code.

We can detect if `.doSomething()` is valid to do on a type `T` using SFINAE, then invert the test, as follows:

```
namespace details {
  template<template<class...>class Z, class, class...Ts>
  struct can_apply:std::false_type{};
  template<template<class...>class Z, class...Ts>
  struct can_apply<Z, std::void_t<Z<Ts...>>, Ts...>:std::true_type{};
}
template<template<class...>class Z, class...Ts>
using can_apply = details::can_apply<Z, void, Ts...>;

template<class X>
using do_something_r = decltype( std::declval<X>().doSomething() );
template<class X>
using can_do_something = can_apply<do_something_r, X>;
```

This detects if `X` is a valid type to `doSomething` on it.

You can use the test like this:

```
static_assert( !can_do_something<RobustClass<2>&>{}, "doSomething should be disabled" );
```

`can_apply` is similar, but not identical, to the C++20 proposed `is_detected`.